# What is the most convenient window splitting strategy for Vim users when using Terminal Multiplexer and Tiling Window Managers?

Tags: neovim, terminal, keyboard-layout

I use Vim/Neovim mostly inside Wezterm, with I3 as my window manager. Also all of them offer tabbed interface. Shortcuts to cycling through the different layers is difficult, even with ergonomic keyboards and fancy key mappings. Why split in Vim if I can manage with my terminal.
Also why split in the terminal if I can split a Vim window and start a `:term` in it and run any cli applications in it.
It is not a technical troubleshoot I am asking. I am just collecting strategies and methodologies around Vim/Multiplexers/TWM in a non Reddit environment.

Comment: "Is there a common strategy"—this is hard to answer. "What is the most convenient"—this is asking for opinions. Convenient for whom? I recommend narrowing your question to focus on a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

The more I spend time with Vim/Neovim the more I tend to stay within Vim:

- For file editing (of course)
- For file browsing with:

  - netrw (`:Ex`, `:Vex`)
  - [NERDTree](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree)
  - [nvim-tree](https://github.com/nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua) for Neovim only
- For fuzzy searching with:

  - [Fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim)
  - [Telescope](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim) for Neovim only
  - [clap](https://github.com/liuchengxu/vim-clap)
- For git:

  - [vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)
- Terminal (`:terminal`)

This allow me to navigate through the windows and tabs using the same shortcut I use to navigate through editors (<kbd>Ctrl w</kbd>`h`, <kbd>Ctrl w</kbd>`l`, ..., `gt`, `gT`)

There are some standard commands that helps to manage the windows and theirsizes:

- <kbd>Ctrl w</kbd>`=` to tile the windows (make them "equal" size)
- `:only` to keep only the current window

There are a number of plugins that may help:

- [vim-maximizer](https://github.com/szw/vim-maximizer) to temporary maximize one window
- [bbye](https://github.com/moll/vim-bbye) to delete or wipeout a buffer without closing the corresponding window
- [winresizer](https://github.com/simeji/winresizer) to resize the windows and move buffers across windows.

This answer is of course personal but spending time answering people's questions and reading expert users I believe part of my answer is shared by others.

Comment: What does "close a buffer" mean? Assuming it's really `:bdelete`, how (why?) would you delete a buffer and keep a window of its content?

Comment: Ah, having read the link, I think your wording is a bit off.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have tried to reformulate to get closer to Vim vocabulary. Tell me how much it is still confusing :-)